# How to use TestNG annotations when the framework is Hybrid and test cases are driven by excel in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-grid, testng-eclipse

When I use a Hybrid framework using Selenium where my test cases are driven by Excel, how can I use TestNG annotations like @Test for my test cases which are in Excel format? Meaning, I have all my test steps converted in Excel as Element, Action and Data combination to trigger an action in UI.

I will be calling a method in main() which in turn calls another method where the reading of Excel and converting the set of rows/columns to frame the Selenium command to trigger events for a test case flow. Given this, how/where can I mention @Test to let TestNG that this is my test method?

I have 1000+ test cases to execute and planning to use Selenium GRID for distributed execution in multiple VMs. In order to do this, I believe we need to have TestNG to let Selenium GRID know that these are my test methods. Any help on this regard is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Bala

Comment: Why do you need TestNG to inform Selenium grid about your test methods? You are going to be using your own framework for creating and sending test cases to the Grid.

Comment: I want Selenium GRID to decide which test cases to execute on which VM from the given pool of VMs. Say I have 50 VMs and 1000 test cases. How can I do the distributed execution in multiple VMs so that 50 test cases are executed at a time each in a VM? You mean to say we can handle all these without using TestNG?

Comment: The VMs will be registered as nodes in the hub of the selenium grid. The hub will decide which nodes will receive the test. This will depend on the driver capabilities you use like browser type, operating system, idle nodes etc. The RemoteDriver object will be instantiated with the URL of the hub and the capabilities object.

Comment: Saying this you should be looking at using a TestNG or Junit to run your tests instead of rolling out your own framework. Incorporate the logic of accessing excel data etc in one of the unit testing frameworks... Much simpler and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Stop wasting time on excel driven solutions. Write normal code for elements and actions. Combine them in your tests. Feed with data which will be populated to the forms. That's all. There are a lot of frameworks which make it an easy task.